# Listar apenas contratos vencidos por ID e não considerar se o ID tiver contrato em vigência

Tags: mysql

Fala galera...

Preciso listar apenas os contratos VENCIDOS, pois quando a empresa renova o contrato, os dados do contrato vencido (antigo) permanecem no BD com status "0". Então temos: 1 contrato vencido (antigo) e 1 em vigência (novo, que foi renovado).

E essa query tá me mostrando a empresa que tem registro de contrato vencido, porém que já tem contrato em vigência (renovado) e isso não tá certo, pois se ela já renovou o contrato, então não tem contrato vencido na data corrente e aí ela não deve aparecer na lista.

O que preciso é que me seja listada as empresas que **não possuem** contrato **vigente** e **vencido**.

Tentei essa query, mas não deu certo:

```
SELECT *

FROM contrato_empresa ce, empresas e

WHERE 

e.emp_id = ce.cte_id_emp AND
ce.cte_status = 0 AND
ce.cte_dt_ini < CURDATE() AND
ce.cte_dt_fim < CURDATE()

ORDER BY e.emp_cidade ASC, e.emp_fantasia ASC
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Se você quer filtrar as empresas que não tenham contratos a vigentes e vencidos, você quer as empresas que não tenham contrato?

Comment: @Diego_F, preciso da lista apenas com contrato VENCIDO, pois quando a empresa renova o contrato, os dados do contrato vencido (antigo) permanecem no BD com status "0". Então temos: 1 contrato vencido (antigo) e 1 em vigência (novo, que foi renovado). E essa query tá me mostrando a empresa que tem registro de contrato vencido, porém que já tem contrato em vigência (renovado) e isso não tá certo, pois se ela já renovou o contrato, então não tem contrato vencido na data corrente e aí ela não deve aparecer na lista, sacou?! :)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro problema na sua query,
dentro do `where` existe isso `ce.cte_id = ce.cte_id` , qual a finalidade de comparar algo com ele mesmo?
Não tem logica,
talvez o problema seja um `c` a mais, ficando `ce.cte_id = e.cte_id`, mas ainda acredito que não exista essa verificação por não atender a segunda forma normal.

Segundo problema,

Você faz uma validação que o contrato tem data de inicio menor que a data atual, OK
`ce.cte_dt_ini < CURDATE()`
Mas esse contrato também precisa ter data final do contrato menor que a data atual, ou seja precisa ser `ce.cte_dt_fim > CURDATE()` e não `ce.cte_dt_fim < CURDATE()` como esta na sua query.
Sua query então deveria ficar assim

```
SELECT *
FROM contrato_empresa ce, empresas e
WHERE 
e.emp_id = ce.cte_id_emp AND
ce.cte_status = 0 AND
ce.cte_dt_ini < CURDATE() AND
ce.cte_dt_fim > CURDATE() AND
ORDER BY e.emp_cidade ASC, e.emp_fantasia ASC
```

Comment: Alexandre, tua sugestão exibe os contratos dentro de vigência com status "0" e não é isso que quero. Quero a lista de contrato VENCIDO, pois quando a empresa renova o contrato, os dados do contrato vencido ficam no BD com status "0". Então temos: 1 contrato vencido e 1 em vigência (novo, renovado). E essa query tá me mostrando a empresa que tem registro de contrato vencido, porém que já tem contrato em vigência (renovado) e isso não tá certo, pois se ela já renovou o contrato, então não tem contrato vencido na data corrente, sacou?! :)

Comment: Esta difícil entender a explicação do que deseja. Entendo que um contrato é renovado no vencimento, ou após o vencimento, do contrato anterior. Dessa forma todos os contratos já vencidos obviamente estarão vencidos na data atual.

Comment: Então se vc quer uma query vencida, não precisa de data inicio, pq o importante é ser maior que a data fim 
```
SELECT *
FROM contrato_empresa ce, empresas e
WHERE 
e.emp_id = ce.cte_id_emp AND
ce.cte_status = 0 AND
ce.cte_dt_fim < CURDATE() AND
ORDER BY e.emp_cidade ASC, e.emp_fantasia ASC
```